# Wicket fails to load resources on form submit after update

Tags: java, spring, path, resources, wicket

as the title says, for some reason Wicket (1.4.20+) is having issues loading resources after a form is submitted.
This problem was non-existent previously, on 1.4.19.

My application's context path is named `/xyz`, and in my web.xml I have mapped the WicketFilter to `/webapp`:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>WicketFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>applicationFactoryClassName</param-name>
        <param-value>org.apache.wicket.spring.SpringWebApplicationFactory</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>WicketFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/webapp/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

so naturally all requests should be handled from `http://host:port/xyz/webapp`

Taking a look in Chrome's console, on load of the page with the form, the resources are loaded properly from `http://host:port/xyz/webapp/resources`, but once I click the Continue button (submit), they are again trying to be loaded from `http://host:port/xyz/resources`. Notice there is no `/webapp` in the second request, so they *all* 404 and nothing happens on press.

Among the lines of the resources trying to be loaded, are: `wicket-event.js`, `wicket-ajax.js`, `modal.js`, which as far as I could tell are all internal to wicket (`org.apache.wicket.*`).
This as far as I can tell is all triggered by an `IActivePageBehaviorListener`.

In the pom, I have updated and am currently on version `1.4.23` on the following: `wicket`, `wicket-extensions`, `wicket-spring` , `wicket-auth-roles`.

My question is, as the only thing I changed was the version of the said dependencies and nothing related to paths whatsoever, what could've introduced this breaking change and how can I fix it? I've been debugging into the wicket framework for hours and I could get nowhere so far...

Comment: I'd check the changelog of 1.4.20 to see what could be the reason. 1.4.20 is very old and I don't remember anyone having such issue with it.

Comment: @martin-g the changelog provides no useful information unfortunately, only one of the bugs reported to be fixed has a patch file attached to it and that doesn't really help either :/

Comment: Have you tried adding the `filterMappingUrlPattern` init param with the value of `/webapp/*`?